# Linux Bash Script: Delete files in folder, but exclude specific files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup, delete-file

I want to create a Shell Script which shall run as a cronjob everyday before I do the backup procedure.

This shell script should delete files in a folder.
But not delete:

- files for the last 7 days
- files created on Sunday for the last 4 weeks
- files created on first of the month for the last 6 month

How can I extend this code:

```
find /path/to/files* -type f -mtime +180 -delete
```

Comment: As a quick hack I would use negative logic: whatever you want to retain - move to some other directory. Delete current directory contents. Restore the required files back.

Answer (score 0):

**plan**

> - read file details ( name and date ) to array
> - loop over array checking for business conditions on the date
> - delete the file if the flag is not set by business logic

**cleanup_files.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# replace with your path to files..
list_files=$(ls ./ -lt --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d" | 
             awk '{ if( $1 != "total" )printf $7","$6"\n"; }' |
             tr '\n' ' ');

four_weeks_ago=$(date -d "now - 4 weeks" +%s);
seven_days_ago=$(date -d "now - 1 weeks" +%s);
six_months_ago=$(date -d "now - 6 months" +%s);

for fil in $list_files
do
  filename=$(printf "$fil\n" | cut -d, -f1);
  fdate=$(printf "$fil\n" | cut -d, -f2);

  flag=0;
  ts=$(date -d "$fdate" +%s);
  wday=$(date -d "$fdate" +%u);
  mday=$(date -d "$fdate" +%d);

  # check if created in last seven days..
  if [ "$ts" -ge "$seven_days_ago" ]; then
    flag=1;
  fi

  # check if created on a sunday in last four weeks
  if [ "$wday" -eq "7" ] && [ "$ts" -ge "$four_weeks_ago" ]; then
    flag=1;
  fi

  # check if file created on first of month for last 6 months
  if [ "$mday" -eq "01" ] && [ "$ts" -ge "$six_months_ago" ]; then
    flag=1;
  fi

  # if flag is not set delete file
  if [ "$flag" -ne "1" ]; then
    printf "deleting $filename..\n";
    # uncomment only after proper testing..
    # rm "$filename";
  fi
#  printf "$fil\n";
done;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you for your answer!
I added after the rm statement this: 
 mkdir -p old;
 mv "$filename" old;